# How to create a bitmap which fills exactly the available space in an WPF Window?

Tags: c#, wpf, graphics

I want to create a WPF application where I can draw **every** single pixel within a WPF window. One challenge here is that `Window` has no property providing the size the window's content should be. This is normally not needed, because the WPF layouting can fit for example a `Grid` perfectly into the available space automatically. But when creating a bitmap, one needs to know exactly how many pixels are available before the layouting of that control happens.

Manipulating pixels in WPF is a bit convoluted. An `Image` is used whose `Source` is set to a `BitmapSource` which is created using an integer array. The pseudo code looks like this:

```csharp
var integerArray = new int[horzontalPixelCount*verticalPixelCount];
var bitmap = BitmapSource.Create(horzontalPixelCount, verticalPixelCount,
  dpiScale.PixelsPerInchX, dpiScale.PixelsPerInchX, PixelFormats.Bgr32, null,
  integerArray , horzontalPixelCount*4);
var image = new Image() {Source = bitmap};
Window.Content = image;
```

Question: how do I know the value of `horzontalPixelCount` and `verticalPixelCount` ?

**Note:**

1. `Window.ActualWidth` and `Window.ActualHeight` provide the complete size of the window, not just the size the content should use.
2. `Window.Content` is null when I need to know how many pixels are available within the window. Code like `((FrameworkElement)MainWindow.Content).ActualHeight` will not work.
3. WPF uses for `Height` and `Width` *device independent units*, but the sizing of `integerArray` must be based on actual pixels.

Answer (score 0):

It was difficult to figure out what space is available within the window where content can be drawn. The solutions I found on StackOverflow were all based on using the size of the `Window.Content`, by default often a Grid. But this caused me 2 problems:

1. That size is only available once the first WPF layout cycle is completed.
2. `Window.Content` will be `null` when I need the available size and only later will I assign something to `Window.Content`.

To get the available size, I came up with the following solution:

```csharp
var border = (Border)GetVisualChild(0);
var horzontalPixelCount = (int)(border.RenderSize.Width*dpiScale.DpiScaleX);
var verticalPixelCount = (int)(border.RenderSize.Height*dpiScale.DpiScaleY);
```

This works because the top most visual child of a `Window` is always a `Border`, even when `Window.Content` is null. Interestingly `border.RenderSize` is already available when `border.ActualSize` is still 0.

WPF uses *device independent units*, which must get converted into how many real pixels are needed for the dimension of the `integerArray`. Nowadays a PC might have 2 monitors with 2 different resolutions. For this to work, one must use a `DpiScale`, which can be found like this:

```csharp
var dpiScale = VisualTreeHelper.GetDpi(this);
```

The complete code:

```csharp
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;

namespace WindowBitmap {
  public partial class MainWindow: Window {
    public MainWindow() {
      InitializeComponent();
      SizeChanged += MainWindow_SizeChanged;
    }

    private void MainWindow_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e) {
      var dpiScale = VisualTreeHelper.GetDpi(this);
      var border = (Border)GetVisualChild(0);
      var horzontalPixelCount = (int)(border.RenderSize.Width*dpiScale.DpiScaleX);
      var verticalPixelCount = (int)(border.RenderSize.Height*dpiScale.DpiScaleY);
      var integerArray = new int[horzontalPixelCount*verticalPixelCount];
      var random = new Random();
      for (int i = 0; i < integerArray.Length; i++) {
        integerArray[i] = random.Next();
      }
      var bitmap = BitmapSource.Create(horzontalPixelCount, verticalPixelCount,
           dpiScale.PixelsPerInchX, dpiScale.PixelsPerInchX, PixelFormats.Bgr32, null,
            integerArray, horzontalPixelCount*4);
      var image = new Image() {Source = bitmap};
      Content = image;
    }
  }
}
```

```xaml
<Window x:Class="WindowBitmap.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WindowBitmap"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" WindowState="Maximized">
</Window>
```